# Postgres - select row if related table has two rows in condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table 'devices' with following structure.

```
id | user_id | device

1 | 12 | tablet
2 | 12 | pc
2 | 12 | mobile
```

This table is related many to one with table "users". One user can have multiple devices, and I would like to select only users that has two devices "tablet" and "pc" for example.

How can I do it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have only 3 distinct devices?

Comment: Not only 3 can by much more.

Comment: The answer I have suggested will `handle` this case.

Comment: I wonder fi will not be better to aggregate colum device to string and in second query search by "like". What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select user_id
from devices
group by user_id 
having count(*) = 2 and max(device) = 'tablet' and min(device) = 'pc'
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69b3558ad2362f0c9af9a5f18760eb7e)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `sub-queries` to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM devices
WHERE user_id NOT IN 
      (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM devices
      WHERE device IN
          (
          SELECT DISTINCT device
          FROM devices
          WHERE device NOT IN ('tablet', 'pc')
          )
      )
AND user_id IN
      (
      SELECT t.user_id
      FROM devices AS t
      INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM devices WHERE device='pc') AS p
      ON t.user_id=p.user_id
      WHERE device='tablet'
      )
```

This is not an optimized query. We can use `JOINS` instead of `WHERE` to make it faster

### Demo here